# Laravel change status on Date after 90 days

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am making a blood donation system where user donates blood on a date, The specific date is saved in the DB now after 90 days I want to enable his status so that user can donate blood again, How can I compare the saved date compare it with today so that exactly user can donate blood again.
I already tried

```
 @if ($donationDate == \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonths(3))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <strong>Donate Now</strong>
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <strong>Sorry you cannot donate blood</strong>
            </div>
        @endif
```

and also

```
 @if ($donationDate >= \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonths(3))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <strong>Donate Now</strong>
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <strong>Sorry you cannot donate blood</strong>
            </div>
        @endif
```

and other `$donationDate->greaterThanEqual(\Carbon\Carbon::now())`
nothing is working

Comment: `if (Carbon::now()->isGreaterThanOrEqualTo($donationDate->addDays(90))) {} `

Comment: You don't say what results you get, so it's a bit difficult to know how to help, but try `@if ($donationDate <= \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonths(3))`

Comment: Not working @Daan this is the result I am getting Call to a member function addDays() on string

Comment: @Litehouse still showing the Cannot Donate Blood

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
@if ($donationDate >= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-90 days')))
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <strong>Donate Now</strong>
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <strong>Sorry you cannot donate blood</strong>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: I have saved the date 2020-11-15 16:09:27.000000 in the database now I manually changed it to 2020-12-15 16:12:03.000000 and it is showing the Donate Now alert it should show only when 90 days have gone.

Comment: Use date('Y-m-d', strtotime($donationDate))

Answer (score 0):

Don't know but this is working for Now!

```
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(90) >= $donationDate)
   <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <strong>Donate Now</strong>
   </div>
@else
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <strong>Sorry you cannot donate blood</strong>
   </div>
@endif
```